# lenovo x230 trackpad stopped working

Tags: 12.04, lenovo, trackpad, x230

I wonder if any person has any ideas for help.

I have a Lenovo x230 running ubuntu 12.04.2 which was working fine until a recent reboot.  After which the touchpad has stopped working.

The trackpointer and external mice all still work and touchpad is not disabled in bios. The buttons in the touchpad also work fine.

Would anyone have any suggestions as to why there would have stopped working or where to look for further clues.

In dmesg I have the following

```
$ dmesg | grep -i touch
[   24.031229] psmouse serio1: synaptics: Touchpad model: 1, fw: 8.1, id: 0x1e2b1, caps: 0xd002a3/0x940300/0x123800
[   24.031240] psmouse serio1: synaptics: serio: Synaptics pass-through port at isa0060/serio1/input0
[   24.066062] input: SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad as /devices/platform/i8042/serio1/input/input13
```

and uname

```
Linux derp 3.5.0-25-generic #39~precise1-Ubuntu SMP Tue Feb 26 00:07:14 UTC 2013 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Answer (score 0):

I was experiencing something similar. I installed a PPA and then rebooted. Installing third party PPA's should be used with caution. The kind person from #ubuntu from FreeNodes told to install the repository listed below, but was quick to tell me to install 'ppa-purge', should the newly added repository not work out.

The following commands were what I used to fix the problem:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:jamesf/lenovofixes
sudo apt-get install trackpoint-psmouse-reload touchpad-togglekey
```

After those were installed, and a reboot, the trackpad worked for me.  Just for completeness sake, I have a Lenovo x230 with Ubuntu 12.04 installed.

`uname -a` gives:

```
Linux XXX version 3.5.0-41-generic #64~precise1-Ubuntu SMP Thu Sep 12 16:50:04 UTC 2013 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```